# What is the equivalent of Thread.SetApartmentState in C++?

Tags: c++, windows, multithreading, com

In C# there is a method `SetApartmentState` in the class `Thread`.
How do I do the same thing in C++?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For unmanaged processes, you control the apartment model used for a thread by passing appropriate parameters to [`CoInitializeEx()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/combaseapi/nf-combaseapi-coinitializeex). Larry Osterman wrote up a *great* little guide to these:

> ...
> When a thread calls `CoInitializeEx` (or
> `CoInitialize`), the thread tells COM
> which of the two apartment types it’s
> prepared to host.  To indicate that
> the thread should live in the MTA, you
> pass the `COINIT_MULTITHREADED` flag to
> `CoInitializeEx`.  To indicate that the
> thread should host an STA, either call
> `CoInitialize` or pass the
> `COINIT_APARTMENTTHREADED` flag to
> `CoInitializeEx`.
> ...

-- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/larryosterman/what-are-these-threading-models-and-why-do-i-care